# How do I create a search bar in win32 API

Tags: winapi, combobox, searchbar

I am working on one project in win32 API. Here, I want the user to type a text in a search bar and the first corresponding words should pop-up. When the user is done with the typing or selects the word, clicking on the 'Process' button should display another message box. I want the search bar should look as this:

[image]

I want each word to display a different message box when the user clicks on the 'Process' button. Implying that, the application must be able to store data such that it can be retrieved. So far, I have this code which can store data and be retrieved.

```
HWND hWndComboBox = CreateWindow (TEXT("COMBOBOX"), TEXT (""),
           CBS_DROPDOWN| CBS_HASSTRINGS | WS_VSCROLL| WS_VISIBLE |WS_CHILD ,
            100, 20, 200, 70,
            hwnd ,(HMENU) NULL, NULL, NULL);

CreateWindow (TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT ("Process "),
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
            200, 100, 70, 20,
            hwnd,(HMENU) NULL, NULL, NULL);

SendMessage  (
    hWndComboBox  ,
    (UINT) CB_ADDSTRING,
    (WPARAM) 0, (LPARAM) TEXT ("Apple"));

SendMessage  (
    hWndComboBox ,
    (UINT) CB_ADDSTRING,
    (WPARAM) 0, (LPARAM) TEXT ("Apple juice"));

    SendMessage (hWndComboBox , CB_GETCURSEL , (WPARAM) 0, (LPARAM) 0);
```

Here, what I cannot do is that there is no default word like "Search Fruits" which clears when the user begins to type. Moreover, when the user selects 'Apple' and clicks on the 'Process' button, no dialog box is displayed. I do not know how to call the message box to respond depending on the user inputs. And also, the small search icon on the right of the search box.

Please what should I do? I am using win32 API Code:Blocks. Any further question for clarification is welcome. Any link or answer is most welcome. Thank you all.

Comment: Look up `CB_SETCUEBANNER`. That should answer one of your questions. You have many questions here. It seems you want somebody to write a program for you from scratch.

Comment: @Barmark Shermirani Thanks for the reply. However, CB_SETCUEBANNER seems not to be part of the functions as CB_GETCURSEL and when I defined it, there is no effect. What should I do please?

Comment: You are using Code::Blocks/MinGW which is missing a lot of stuff. Add `#define CB_SETCUEBANNER 0x1703`. Note that `CB_SETCUEBANNER` is Unicode only. You have to use `SendMessageW(hWndComboBox, CB_SETCUEBANNER, 0, LPARAM(L"Search..."));`

Comment: If you want to continue using MinGW at least switch to MinGW-w64 which implements a lot of the missing stuff. Does Code::Blocks ship with MinGW itself?

Comment: @Barmark Thanks for the reply. However, it does not still have any effect in the combobox. I guess we are trying to make a default shady word 'Search' appear in the combobox which writes off when the user begins to type. What should I do please?

Comment: Edit your question and show how you are using `CB_SETCUEBANNER`. Show return value of `SendMessage(CB_SETCUEBANNER...)` and show result of `GetLastError`